# Symfony - select from multiple tables

Tags: optimization, select, symfony1

I've got gallery and to display it I need to get few information like number of comments, rating, favs etc. I do something like under, but it doesn't seem good for me.
How to do it in a better way? Maybe is there any way to do it in one query, without subqueries?

I could add to table Image columns like number of comments, favs etc., but if something go wrong then statistics won't be real. Counting it each time is more reliable.

```
$images = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT img
    FROM AcmeMainBundle:Image img
    WHERE img.category = :category
    ORDER BY img.order ASC, img.id DESC')
    ->setParameter('category', $category)
    ->getResult();



$comments = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT i.id, COUNT(i.id) as c_count
    FROM AcmeMainBundle:ImgComment c
    JOIN c.image i
    WHERE i.category = :category
    GROUP BY c.image')
    ->setParameter('category', $category)
    ->getResult();      



$ratings = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT i.id, SUM(r.rating) as suma, COUNT(r.rating) as votes
    FROM AcmeMainBundle:ImgRating r
    JOIN r.image i
    WHERE i.category = :category
    GROUP BY r.image')
    ->setParameter('category', $category)
    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, thi is okay. If you don't have thousands of different categories you are pretty lucky that sql caches your queries and results. It also depends on the average amounth of ratings per image for the calculation. Try to copy the generated sql query and benchmark it in Sql:

`EXPLAIN $yourquery`

Mind that you should have indexes on the fields that are used for subquery calculation that are not updated often (which should be the case for image ratings).

Maybe your want to have look into your mysql statictics, whether your query_cache size do fit. It really depends on the size of the project.

Hope that helps you out a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've got realations in this tables like "user_id" and "image_id" and i already have indexes on this fields :). I've got few more tables with similar informations like 'favourties' etc. Summary it's about 12 queries per page to get all of these information including subsite content and it's cause of my question, i'm not sure if it isn't too many?